# How to write Data from Excel file into a HashMap for more than one column

Tags: java, excel, hashmap, switch-statement, apache-poi

I have written a logic in java, to write data from excel to HashMap by iterating each column from excel.

Please find the method written below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class testclass {
public static Map<String,List<String>> getInputData(File dmnPath, File excelPath) throws IOException {
        //preparation input data list
        Map<String,List<String>> inputMap =new  HashMap<String,List<String>>();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> values2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> values3 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> values4 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> values5 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> values6 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> values7 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> values8 = new ArrayList<>();

        // Reading file from local directory
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(excelPath);
        ExtractingHeaders ext = new ExtractingHeaders();
        
        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook XS = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        int numberofsheets = XS.getNumberOfSheets();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofsheets; i++) {
            if (XS.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Sheet1")) {

                XSSFSheet XSS = XS.getSheetAt(i);

                DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

                int k = 0;
                for(String key: ext.getInputHeaders(dmnPath, excelPath)) {    // headerDetails.getInputParam() nned to delete
                    inputMap.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
                    Iterator<Row> r = XSS.iterator();

                    while (r.hasNext()) {                           // loop for excel row count     
                        Row row = r.next();
                        if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
        
                        String cellValue;
                        switch(k) {     // Need to replace switch case to dynamic
                        case 0:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                values.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                            values.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                    values2.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                values2.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values2);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                values3.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                values3.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values3);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                values4.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                values4.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values4);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                values5.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                values5.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values5);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                values6.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                values6.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values6);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                values7.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                values7.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values7);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(k));
                            if (cellValue.equals("")) {
                                values8.add(null);
                            }
                            else {
                                values8.add(cellValue);
                            }
                            inputMap.put(key, values8);
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("No case statemnt in ReadExcelTestCase input class");
                        }
            }
                    k++;
                }
            }
        
        // Closing file output streams
        XS.close();
        file.close();
        
        }
        return inputMap;
    }
}
```

To write data from excel to HashMap by iterating each column, I have used switch case here. But its not a best way, because in future no. of columns may increase.

Any alternate suggestions please.

Example excel sheet attached here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8MQE.png)

Expected output:

```
{Column1=[C1,C2,C3], Column2=[C2,C3,C4], Column3=[4,56,3], Column4=[C4,C5,C6], Column5=[C5,C6,C7], Column6=[4,7,9], Column7=[C7,C8,C9], Column8=[5,5,6]}
```